# Bootstrap dropdown list float left

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have a site link: http://www.dentalmarketing.com.au/stage/test/2/

If you click on the menu link SUB SITES, as you can see the drop down list appears as normal list. Is there a way to float the LI list in Bootstrap CSS so that the list would appear like inline?

I have tried inserting my css

```
.mainnav ul.dropdown-menu > li {   
float:left !important;
}
```

But somehow it just doesn't work. Thanks much for your time and expertise.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with `display: inline-block` then you also need to set a width to the `ul`

You could also use float... here is what the css should look like with either way :
width's may vary

```
.open > .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 400px;
}
```

or

```
.open > .dropdown-menu {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 400px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much spent an hour looking for that solution. cheers man!

Comment: Not a problem. Glad to help